# Перечисления Java

Tags: java, enum

Нужно создать перечисление неких организаций, но в задании сказано, что перечисление должно содержать название организации и цену услуг. Как я понимаю, перечисление - это набор единичных констант. Как в перечисление записать и название организации и цену услуг?

P.S. Не исключаю, что само задание не корректно.

Текст задания как есть. Сумму оплаты я заменил на цену услуг.

> Должен быть минимум один интерфейс, абстрактный класс и один
>   внутренний класс, а также перечисление для организаций из которых
>   пришли слушетели. Перечисление должно помимо названия
>   организации содержать полное название организации и сумму оплаты.

Comment: Уточните текст задания. Скорее всего ошибка в формулировке или интерпретации.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Возможно имеется ввиду именно это

```
public enum Organizations {

        /**
         * Организация А
         */
        A("Name1", BigDecimal.valueOf(100)),
        /**
         * Организация B
         */
        B("Name2", BigDecimal.valueOf(200)),
        /**
         * Организация C
         */
        C("Name3", BigDecimal.valueOf(300)),
        /**
         * Организация D
         */
        D("Name4", BigDecimal.valueOf(400)),
        /**
         * Организация E
         */
        E("Name5", BigDecimal.valueOf(500));

        private Organizations(String name, BigDecimal price) {
            this.price = price;
            this.name = name;
        }

        /**
         * Возвращает цену услуг
         *
         * @return BigDecimal цена услуг
         */
        public BigDecimal getPrice() {
            return price;
        }

        /**
         * Возвращает наименование
         *
         * @return String наименование
         */
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        private BigDecimal price;
        private String name;

    }
```

В коде потом можно получать как название `Organizations.A.getName()` так и цену `Organizations.A.getPrice()`

Comment: Я б рекомендовал бы написать в начале почему такое возможно) типа  Запись перечисления "public enum Test" равноценна "abstract class Test extends java.lang.Enum" ... поэтому можно писать всё как в классе..бла бла бла